# Create rows in R, based on pair combinations of existing rows

Tags: r, rows, expand

**I have**

|  | col_a | col_c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 01001 |
| 2 | B | 01002 |
| 3 | C | 01003 |
| 4 | D | 01004 |
| 5 | E | 01005 |
| 6 | F | 01006 |

**I want**

|  | col_a | col_b | col_c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | A | 01001 |
| 2 | A | B | 01002 |
| 3 | A | C | 01003 |
| 4 | A | D | 01004 |
| 5 | A | E | 01005 |
| 6 | A | F | 01006 |
| 7 | B | A | 01001 |
| 8 | B | B | 01002 |
| 9 | B | C | 01003 |
| 10 | B | D | 01004 |
| 11 | B | E | 01005 |
| .. | .. | .. |  |
| 24 | F | E | 01005 |
| 25 | F | F | 01006 |

I feel like this is simple but its 4:30 am and my brain is no longer working please help.

I have tried

```
#Set up a fake key to join on (just a constant)
df <- df %>% mutate(k = 1) 

 #Perform the join, remove the key
main_df %>% 
  full_join(df, by = "k") %>%
 select(-k)
```

I've also tried

```
df <-
merge(
  x = df,
  y = df[, c("col_a",
             "col_c")],
     by.x = "a",
     by.y = "a",
     all = TRUE
   )

  df <-
   merge(
     x = df[, c("col_a",
                     "col_c")],
     y = main_df,
     by.x = "col_a",
     by.y = "col_a",
     all.x = TRUE
   )
```

I have tried MANY combinations of the above solutions, not just the ones listed here. No avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below

```
out <- merge(data.frame(col_b = df$col_a), df, all = TRUE)[c("col_a", "col_b", "col_c")]
```

or

```
out <- with(
  df,
  cbind(
    setNames(rev(expand.grid(col_a, col_a)), c("col_a","col_b")),
    col_c = rep(col_c, by = nrow(df))
  )
)
```

and you will see

```
> out
   col_a col_b col_c
1      A     A  1001
2      A     B  1002
3      A     C  1003
4      A     D  1004
5      A     E  1005
6      A     F  1006
7      B     A  1001
8      B     B  1002
9      B     C  1003
10     B     D  1004
11     B     E  1005
12     B     F  1006
13     C     A  1001
14     C     B  1002
15     C     C  1003
16     C     D  1004
17     C     E  1005
18     C     F  1006
19     D     A  1001
20     D     B  1002
21     D     C  1003
22     D     D  1004
23     D     E  1005
24     D     F  1006
25     E     A  1001
26     E     B  1002
27     E     C  1003
28     E     D  1004
29     E     E  1005
30     E     F  1006
31     F     A  1001
32     F     B  1002
33     F     C  1003
34     F     D  1004
35     F     E  1005
36     F     F  1006
```